# Using a ControlParameter in FilterParameters when the property is null

Tags: asp.net, null, datalist, selectedvalue, controlparameter

I have a DataList and FormView; they have separate datasources, though they pull the same info.  The FormView's datasource has a FilterExpression to pull whatever's been selected on the DataList.  On first load, the SelectedValue of the DataList is null (naturally).  I expect the FilterExpression to result in zero rows, but it doesn't.  If I set the DefaultValue to 0, it does, but then the parameter never updates when I select something from the DataList.  Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, (according to [this post](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/.NET/ASP.NET/Q_24007280.html)) there's a bug with this.  The solution is to attach an OnFiltering handler like this (I've made a few enhancements):

```
protected void FilteringCheck(Object sender, SqlDataSourceFilteringEventArgs e)
{
    // Make sure there are no null parameters.
    for (int i = 0; i < e.ParameterValues.Count; i++)
    {
        if (e.ParameterValues[i] == null)
        {
            switch (((System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView)sender).FilterParameters[i].Type)
            {
                case TypeCode.Int16:
                case TypeCode.Int32:
                case TypeCode.Int64:
                    e.ParameterValues[i] = -1;
                    break;
                case TypeCode.Byte:
                    e.ParameterValues[i] = 0;
                    break;
                case TypeCode.Char:
                case TypeCode.String:
                    e.ParameterValues[i] = string.Empty;
                    break;
                case TypeCode.DateTime:
                    e.ParameterValues[i] = new DateTime();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```